# Deployment: Side by side install causes "another version of this product is already installed" error

Tags: c#, deployment

When deploying another instance of a C# Windows Service the following error message is encountered:

> “Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of
>   this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing
>   version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel”

**Now the problem is that we actually do want 2 instances of the same service and version deployed.**

In this case each service does the same thing for a customer that distributes 2 different brands. Rather than creating a multi-tenant application it was easier to just sell an additional license to an existing product.

So my questions:

1. Is the only way to get around this to alter the GUID for the product code of the service?
2. If so how can this been done automatically so I don't have to rebuild on each deploy? This error message kicks in prior to the install wizard so using custom screens during installation is not an option to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the difference between two instances of the services?

Comment: Same functionality, same configuration schema but different configuration file settings i.e. different warehouse endpoints, different message recipients, different sql server instances etc per brand.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the setup project in the solution explorer, and then have a look at the properties tab, there is a "detect newer version installed" property, if you set it to false it should work fine, however remember to install the app in a different location..

Comment: Note that windows will not allow more than 1 windows service to be installed with the same service name

Comment: The service name is altered in the install wizard custom boxes but this error occurs prior to that. Unfortunately the detect newer version property has no bearing on this use case. In this case Windows is detecting the same instance version. So this is a side by sideissue not an upgrade/downgrade issue. If i alter the GUID it works but Im looking for an automatic means of doing that. Its not a retail product so its not a huge deal but it would be nice not to have to recompile the deploy proj every time we secure a new customer with multibrands. No it's not cost effective to rewrite the app. :)

Comment: Ah that's my bad, I didn't read the question too well, It sounds like you need to implement a way in the service to use multiple settings?

Comment: Some answers [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/54386/i-want-to-install-an-msi-twice) can be helpful.